# Angular unit-test - mocking method in controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to mock the method of service in the controller. I know how to mock simple service like service.method, but not like this one. I dont know how to mock "action.user.update". If i tried to spy on it, i received an error 'Cannot read property 'update' of undefined'.

[JsFidleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/3oavnmev/)

My service:

```
.service('action', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var service = {};

     service.user = {
        update: function (data, config) {
             return service.run({
                name: config.name,
                call: $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/user/edit",
                    data: data
                }),
                success: config.success,
                error: config.error
            });
        }
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

Comment: Where is the 'action'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got half way there

```
$provide.value('action', action);
```

where action should be an object you create in unit tests

i.e.

```
action = {
    user: {
        update: jasmine.createSpy('action.user.update')
    }
}
$provide.value('action', action);
```

and then in test

```
scope.saveUser()
expect(action.user.update).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/3oavnmev/1/